# Localization in Ruby on Rails: nested values in *.yml file

Tags: localization, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A localization yml file *.yml

```
errors:
    template:
      body:       "Body error message"
        header:
          one:    "1 error "
          other:  "%{count} errores"
```

For some reason it throws an error on a page `"(/home/alex/RubymineProjects/psg/config/locales/es.yml): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 248 column 7"` which means there is something wrong in it.

If I delete `"Body error message"` (only the value, not `body` key) then everything is good, there is no error on a page.

What is wrong? How do I define the key `body` **with a value** and its nested values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is wrong: `body` and `header` should be at the same depth:

```
errors:
  template:
    body:       "Body error message"
    header:
      one:    "1 error "
      other:  "%{count} errores"
```